# XML : language to improve UI (Xamarin)

Tags: xml, android-layout, xslt, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm developing, for the first time, a hybrid app, something like instagram or social networks where you can chat with everyone but you must login for the first time, then no login needed but only network connection (like istagram or facebook).

But I have a problem with XML, this is my first time with it and I don't know how to modify button, navigation bar and all the other tools...
With HTML I used CSS and I heard that in XML there are the same stuffs called XSLT.
I'm searching on the internet, W3School, YouTube...Probably I'm doing it wrong but I don't find something useful that can help me.

So my question is : 
Which is the language that I can use to modify the style of my XML objects? (Button, navigation bar...).

If I want to move them across the screen, change color, shades, on-click animations, corners...

I'm new in Xamarin and C# so if you can also tell me something more to help me moving my first steps in this world it will be very useful.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/

Comment: I didn't know this page. Thank you!

Comment: @MichealRoss Hi , if have solved it , remember to mark the answer or share your solution in answer . Then other people will know the solution :-)

Comment: @Jason How can I mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that you can translate XML with XSLT, but that isn't what you are looking for here.

Similar to Windows WPF, Xamarin.Forms uses XAML for declaring the UI. Unfortunately the entire XAML topic is a bit too much to put it into a SO answer. However, if you know HTML, 
I strongly advise looking into the xamarin.forms documentation to get an understanding of how XAML works.

In terms of modifying existing elements you have several options:

- Change Colors, Fonts, and other properties the element provides by setting these in XAML
- Change properties of the element from the codebehind
- Get new Elements from installing Nuget packages / plugins
- Build your own Elements by deriving from standard elements (Button, Label, whatsoever) and add properties, these Elements don't have by default. However, this means you have to implement custom renderers for each target platform which add the missing functionality
- Include a 2D rendering engine like SkiaSharp into your app and write the actual drawing and interactivity code by yourself

Please note that the last two items on that list are a bit more advanced and require a deeper understanding and expertise, you might not yet have when jumping into Xamarin for the first time.

I would recommend that you look for some Xamarin.Forms xaml tutorials. Googling that should give you plenty of good results, be it a web article or a tutorial video. In addition, Microsoft offers quite a pretty decent documentation and sample projects, so you could download a sample project, open it in your IDE and play around with it to see what changing a particular value would result in your app.

Comment: mmmh, it seems an hard world to understand but thank you I appreciate your help. I'll do my best!

Comment: Don't go to hard on yourself. You'll find out that it is easier to understand as you might think right now and with HTML knowledge, you should be ready to go within a few days.